# Кол-во значков на рабочем столе

Tags: delphi

Как узнать количество значков на рабочем столе, если я вот так узнал указатель на окно, содержащее значки:

```
var
  HDesktop :HWND;
//...
  HDesktop := FindWindow('ProgMan', nil);
  HDesktop := GetWindow(HDesktop, GW_CHILD);
  HDesktop := GetWindow(HDesktop, GW_CHILD);
```

Comment: Для справки: кошерный IActiveDesktop в висте+ не поддерживает подсчет элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таким образом вы нашли окно с классом `SysListView32`.
Надо теперь просто послать ему сообщение `LVM_GETITEMCOUNT` или вызвать

```
ItemCount := ListView_GetItemCount(HDesktop);
```

которая это сообщение и посылает...

ЗЫ `uses CommCtrl;`

Comment: Хак в том, что метод трогает приватные члены :-) Однако я считаю этот хак более предпочтительным решением, чем зоопарк быстро меняющихся интерфейсов (см. мой коммент об отставке IActiveDesktop)

Comment: Никакого хака не вижу в том, чтобы послать сообщение окну. Весь CommCtrl в таких хаках и половина vcl тоже. Хэндлы окон не приватные, а очень даже public.

IActiveDesktop - [этот?][1] Legacy Shell Features. This feature is supported only under Windows XP or earlier. 

ТС спрашивал про ProgMan...

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776830(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Вы так говорите, как будто PROGMAN это не legacy :-) Сообщение - не хак, нахождение SysListView32 - хак.

Comment: ProgMan - это совместимость, а не legacy.

"C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\WS32.EXE" - хакерская утилита?

Впрочем смысла спорить не вижу.